# Read a file and copy each words in its correspondence file

Tags: sorting, unix, grep, alphabetical

I read a file with words and I have to create a directory containing 26 dictionary files, as follows: the first file contains, alphabetically ordered, one per line, all the words in the text file starting with the letter A;, the second with the letterB; etc...

```
apple, banana, almond, ...
```

words.txt

```
almond
apple
```

a.txt

```
banana
```

b.txt

The code I write is:

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=( {a..z} )

for i in chars
do 
    grep '^$i' words.txt > new.txt
    sort new.txt > $i.txt
done
```

but I doesnt do anything. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop over the content of the array. Use

```
for i in ${chars[@]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Note that if you need a "cursor" to run from a to z, you can create that directly in the `for` loop, you don't need to set that up first.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {a..z}
do 
  grep -o "\b$i\w*" words.txt | sort > $i.txt
done
```